# Qt: How to implement simple internal drag&drop for reordering items in QListView using a custom model

Tags: qt, listview, drag-and-drop, model-view

I have a `QList` of custom structs and i'm using custom model class (subclass of `QAbstractListModel`) to display those structs in 1-dimensional QListView. I have overriden the methods`rowCount`, `flags` and `data` to construct a display string from the struct elements.

Now i would like to enable internal drag&drop to be able to reorder the items in the list by dragging them and dropping them between some other items, but this task seems unbeliavably complicated. What exactly do i need to override and what parameters do i need to set? I tried a lot of things, i tried

```
view->setDragEnabled( true );
view->setAcceptDrops( true );
view->setDragDropMode( QAbstractItemView::InternalMove );
view->setDefaultDropAction( Qt::MoveAction );
```

I tried

```
Qt::DropActions supportedDropActions() const override {
    return Qt::MoveAction;
}
Qt::ItemFlags flags( const QModelIndex & index ) const override{
    return QAbstractItemModel::flags( index ) | Qt::ItemIsDragEnabled;
}
```

I tried implementing `insertRows` and `removeRows`, but it still doesn't work.

I haven't found a single example of a code doing exactly that. The official documentation goes very deeply into how view/model pattern works and how to make drag&drops from external apps or from other widgets, but i don't want any of that. I only want simple internal drag&drop for manual reordering of the items in that one list view.

Can someone please help me? Or i'll get nuts from this.

EDIT: adding insertRows/removeRows implementation on request:

```
bool insertRows( int row, int count, const QModelIndex & parent ) override
{
    QAbstractListModel::beginInsertRows( parent, row, row + count - 1 );

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        AObjectListModel<Object>::objectList.insert( row, Object() );

    QAbstractListModel::endInsertRows();
    return true;
}

bool removeRows( int row, int count, const QModelIndex & parent ) override
{
    if (row < 0 || row + count > AObjectListModel<Object>::objectList.size())
        return false;

    QAbstractListModel::beginRemoveRows( parent, row, row + count - 1 );

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        AObjectListModel<Object>::objectList.removeAt( row );

    QAbstractListModel::endRemoveRows();
    return true;
}
```

`objectList` is QList where Object is template parameter.

Comment: hello,  can you show insertRows and removeRows implementacion?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you want to reorganize items in a custom model, you have to implement all needed actions:
- how to insert and remove a row
- how to get and set data
- how to serialize items (build the mimedata)
- how to unserialize items

An example with a custom model with a `QStringList` as data source:

The minimal implementation of the model should be:

```
class CustomModel: public QAbstractListModel
{
public:
    CustomModel()
    {
        internalData = QString("abcdefghij").split("");
    }
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
    {
        return internalData.length();
    }
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
    {
        if (!index.isValid() || index.parent().isValid())
            return QVariant();
        if (role != Qt::DisplayRole)
            return QVariant();
        return internalData.at(index.row());
    }
private:
    QStringList internalData;   
};
```

We have to add the way to insert/remove rows and set the data:

```
    bool setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role = Qt::DisplayRole)
    {
        if (role != Qt::DisplayRole)
            return false;
        internalData[index.row()] = value.toString();
        return true;
    }
    bool insertRows(int row, int count, const QModelIndex &parent)
    {
        if (parent.isValid())
            return false;
        for (int i = 0; i != count; ++i)
            internalData.insert(row + i, "");
        return true;
    }
    bool removeRows(int row, int count, const QModelIndex &parent)
    {
        if (parent.isValid())
            return false;
        beginRemoveRows(parent, row, row + count - 1);
        for (int i = 0; i != count; ++i)
            internalData.removeAt(row);
        endRemoveRows();
        return true;
    }
```

For the drag and drop part:

First, we need to define a mime type to define the way we will deserialize the data:

```
    QStringList mimeTypes() const
    {
        QStringList types;
        types << CustomModel::MimeType;
        return types;
    }
```

Where `CustomModel::MimeType` is a constant string like `"application/my.custom.model"`

The method `canDropMimeData` will be used to check if the dropped data are legit or not. So, we can discard external data:

```
    bool canDropMimeData(const QMimeData *data,
        Qt::DropAction action, int /*row*/, int /*column*/, const QModelIndex& /*parent*/)
    {
        if ( action != Qt::MoveAction || !data->hasFormat(CustomModel::MimeType))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
```

Then, we can create our mime data based on the internal data:

```
    QMimeData* mimeData(const QModelIndexList &indexes) const
    {
        QMimeData* mimeData = new QMimeData;
        QByteArray encodedData;

        QDataStream stream(&encodedData, QIODevice::WriteOnly);

        for (const QModelIndex &index : indexes) {
            if (index.isValid()) {
                QString text = data(index, Qt::DisplayRole).toString();
                stream << text;
            }
        }
        mimeData->setData(CustomModel::MimeType, encodedData);
        return mimeData;
    }
```

Now, we have to handle the dropped data. We have to deserialize the mime data, insert a new row to set the data at the right place (for a `Qt::MoveAction`, the old row will be automaticaly removed. That why we had to implement `removeRows`):

```
bool dropMimeData(const QMimeData *data,
        Qt::DropAction action, int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent)
    {
        if (!canDropMimeData(data, action, row, column, parent))
            return false;

        if (action == Qt::IgnoreAction)
            return true;
        else if (action  != Qt::MoveAction)
            return false;

        QByteArray encodedData = data->data("application/my.custom.model");
        QDataStream stream(&encodedData, QIODevice::ReadOnly);
        QStringList newItems;
        int rows = 0;

        while (!stream.atEnd()) {
            QString text;
            stream >> text;
            newItems << text;
            ++rows;
        }

        insertRows(row, rows, QModelIndex());
        for (const QString &text : qAsConst(newItems))
        {
            QModelIndex idx = index(row, 0, QModelIndex());
            setData(idx, text);
            row++;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

If you want more info on the drag and drop system in Qt, take a look at [the documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#using-drag-and-drop-with-item-views).

Comment: Awesome, thank's for this detailed answer. You're my saviour. The documentation says the QAbstractListModel has default implementations of `mimeData` and `dropMimeData` which work well in most cases as long as you correctly implement `data`, `setData`, `insertRows` and `removeRows`. That's what confused me. After some more fiddling i found out how they meant it and why it doesn't work that way. I will write a complementary answer that will explain it.

Comment: Feel free to edit my answer if it's wrong or if it can be improved.

Comment: It's not wrong. I only have one question: Why do you check if parent index is valid and abort in those cases?

Comment: The `parent` is valid for structure based on a tree and the model is a list. So, the model cannot handle an item with a parent.

Comment: This was very helpful and it worked for me – thank you. Question: if I’m understanding everything correctly, moving an item involves creating a new object and destructing the old one, no?

Answer (score 12):

In addition to the Romha's great answer, i would like to supplement few more details about how it works and what's confusing on it.

The official [documentation says](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#accepting-dropped-data) the `QAbstractItemModel` has default implementations of `mimeTypes`, `mimeData` and `dropMimeData` which should work for internal move and copy operations as long as you correctly implement `data`, `setData`, `insertRows` and `removeRows`.

And from certain point of view, they were right. It does work without overriding `mimeData` and `dropMimeData`, but only when your underlying data structure contains only single strings, those that are returned from `data` and received in `setData` as DisplayRole. When you have a list of compound objects (like i have) with multiple elements, only one of which is used for the DisplayRole, for example

```
struct Elem {
    QString name;
    int i;
    bool b;
}

QVariant data( const QModelIndex & index, int role ) const override
{
    return objectList[ index.row() ].name;
}
bool setData( const QModelIndex & index, const QVariant & value, int role ) override
{
    objectList[ index.row() ].name = value.toString();
}
```

then the default implementations will actually do this

```
QVariant data = data( oldIndex, Qt::DisplayRole );
insertRows( newIndex, 1 )
setData( newIndex, data, Qt::DisplayRole )
removeRows( oldIndex, 1 )
```

and therefore only correctly move the names and leave the rest of the struct as is. Which makes sense now, but the system is so complicated that i didn't realize it before.

Therefore custom `mimeData` and `dropMimeData` are required to move the whole content of the structs

Answer (score 5):

Here is a evidenced example for you ,but in Python:

```
import sys
from PySide6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PySide6.QtCore import (Qt, QStringListModel, QModelIndex,
                          QMimeData, QByteArray, QDataStream, QIODevice)
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QMainWindow, QListView, QAbstractItemView, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QWidget)


class DragDropListModel(QStringListModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(DragDropListModel, self).__init__(parent)
        # self.myMimeTypes = 'application/vnd.text.list' # 可行

        # self.myMimeTypes = "text/plain" # 可行
        self.myMimeTypes = 'application/json'  # 可行

    def supportedDropActions(self):
        # return Qt.CopyAction | Qt.MoveAction  # 拖动时复制并移动相关项目
        return Qt.MoveAction  # 拖动时移动相关项目

    def flags(self, index):
        defaultFlags = QStringListModel.flags(self, index)

        if index.isValid():
            return Qt.ItemIsDragEnabled | Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled | defaultFlags
        else:
            return Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled | defaultFlags

    def mimeTypes(self):
        return [self.myMimeTypes]

    # 直接将indexes里面对应的数据取出来，然后打包进了QMimeData()对象，并返回
    def mimeData(self, indexes):
        mmData = QMimeData()
        encodedData = QByteArray()
        stream = QDataStream(encodedData, QIODevice.WriteOnly)

        for index in indexes:
            if index.isValid():
                text = self.data(index, Qt.DisplayRole)
                stream << text  # 测试，也行
                # stream.writeQString(str(text))  # 原始, 可行

        mmData.setData(self.myMimeTypes, encodedData)
        return mmData

    def canDropMimeData(self, data, action, row, column, parent):
        if data.hasFormat(self.myMimeTypes) is False:
            return False
        if column > 0:
            return False
        return True

    def dropMimeData(self, data, action, row, column, parent):
        if self.canDropMimeData(data, action, row, column, parent) is False:
            return False

        if action == Qt.IgnoreAction:
            return True

        beginRow = -1
        if row != -1:  # 表示
            print("case 1: ROW IS NOT -1, meaning inserting in between, above or below an existing node")
            beginRow = row
        elif parent.isValid():
            print("case 2: PARENT IS VALID, inserting ONTO something since row was not -1, "
                  "beginRow becomes 0 because we want to "
                  "insert it at the beginning of this parents children")
            beginRow = parent.row()
        else:
            print("case 3: PARENT IS INVALID, inserting to root, "
                  "can change to 0 if you want it to appear at the top")
            beginRow = self.rowCount(QModelIndex())
        print(f"row={row}, beginRow={beginRow}")

        encodedData = data.data(self.myMimeTypes)
        stream = QDataStream(encodedData, QIODevice.ReadOnly)
        newItems = []
        rows = 0

        while stream.atEnd() is False:
            text = stream.readQString()
            newItems.append(str(text))
            rows += 1

        self.insertRows(beginRow, rows, QModelIndex())  # 先插入多行
        for text in newItems:  # 然后给每一行设置数值
            idx = self.index(beginRow, 0, QModelIndex())
            self.setData(idx, text)
            beginRow += 1

        return True


class DemoDragDrop(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(DemoDragDrop, self).__init__(parent)

        # 设置窗口标题
        self.setWindowTitle('drag&drop in PySide6')
        # 设置窗口大小
        self.resize(480, 320)

        self.initUi()

    def initUi(self):
        self.vLayout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.listView = QListView(self)
        self.listView.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)
        self.listView.setDragEnabled(True)
        self.listView.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.listView.setDropIndicatorShown(True)
        self.ddm = DragDropListModel()  # 该行和下面4行的效果类似
        # self.listView.setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView.InternalMove)
        # self.listView.setDefaultDropAction(Qt.MoveAction)
        # self.listView.setDragDropOverwriteMode(False)
        # self.ddm = QStringListModel()

        self.ddm.setStringList(['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3', 'Item 4'])
        self.listView.setModel(self.ddm)

        self.printButton = QPushButton("Print")

        self.vLayout.addWidget(self.listView)
        self.vLayout.addWidget(self.printButton)

        self.printButton.clicked.connect(self.printModel)

    def printModel(self):  # 验证移动view中项目后，背后model中数据也发生了移动
        print(self.ddm.data(self.listView.currentIndex()))


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('fusion')
    window = DemoDragDrop()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```